# How to stop the player from jumping twice when in the air?

Tags: java, controller, libgdx, box2d

My player jumps twice when in the air which I don't want. Here is the code from play class where when the user presses space, the player jumps but it jumps one more time when in the air when spacebar is pressed again.I tried to check if the player is on the ground or not and it gives the false value whether player is on the ground or not and hence the player does not jump with this code

When i remove the second if statement the player jumps once in the air and when pressed again jumps from the air.

Here is my mycontactListener class where it checks whether the player is on the ground or not.For some reason it does not calculate the numFootContacts of the player when on the ground.

How to stop the player from jumping twice or when in the air?

Comment: Did you consider adding some debugging to `isPlayerOnGround()` to figure why it's returning `true` when you think it should be returning `false`?

Comment: it shd return false when the player is in the air and true when the player is on the ground. I didn't debug it yet. By default its returning false as numFootContact is 0.

Comment: If it turns out that it's returning true when you think the player should not be on the ground, then start checking if `numFootContacts` is being updated correctly.  And then continue following the breadcrumb trail till you find the root cause.  Debugging is a skill that takes time to learn.  You've got a good basis here, but it'll take practice till it gets to be second nature.  A good rule to live by is "Never assume that any part of your program works correctly till you've seen it doing the correct thing in all cases."  Good luck!

Comment: In contactListener class, it is getting the fixture for player and diamond but not the foot. I cannot get the third fixture named foot. How to get that?

Comment: Do you need the foot?  Can you not just use contact between the player and the diamond?

Comment: I need it for the collision between tile and foot...! Later on, I have to change the colour of the tile to which the player will land on!

Answer (score 2):

It's better to check if the y velocity value is 0. In fact you can jump only if you aren't jumping or falling, I mean only if you are standing.

Here is the code:

```
if(MyInput.isPressed(MyInput.SPACE) &&
    player.getBody().getLinearVelocity().y==0)
    player.getBody().applyForceToCenter(0, 150, true);
```